# sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm getting an error message when I run my code using Python 3.5.1:

```
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

I can't find mistakes in my code, I think the error isn't even in **my** code.

This is my code:

```
import re

numberRegexa = re.compile(r'06\d{8}')
numberRegexb = re.compile(r'06 \d{8}')
numberRegexc = re.compile(r'31 6 \d{8}')
numberRegexd = re.compile(r'+31 6 \d{8}')
numberRegexe = re.compile(r'316\d{8}')
numberRegexf = re.compile(r'+316\d{8}')
numberRegexg = re.compile(r'316 \d{8}')
numberRegexh = re.compile(r'+316 \d{8}')
numberRegexi = re.compile(r'31 6\d{8}')
numberRegexj = re.compile(r'+31 6\d{8}')

##numberRegexAll = [
##    (1,  numberRegex06a),
##    (2,  numberRegex06b),
##    (3,  numberRegex31a),
##    (4,  numberRegex31b),
##    (5,  numberRegex31c),
##    (6,  numberRegex31d),
##    (7,  numberRegex31e),
##    (8,  numberRegex31f),
##    (9,  numberRegex31g),
##    (10, numberRegex31h),
##]

def searchNumber():
    result = numberRegex06a.search(userInput)
    print('Found: ' + result.group())

userInput = input("Insert text you'd like searched:\n")
searchNumber()
```

And this is my log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Hibuna/Desktop/asdsad.py", line 6, in <module>
    numberRegexd = re.compile(r'+31 6 \d{8}')

  File "C:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\re.py", line 224, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)

  File "C:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\re.py", line 293, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)

  File "C:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\sre_compile.py", line 536, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)

  File "C:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\sre_parse.py", line 829, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)

  File "C:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\sre_parse.py", line 437, in
_parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))

  File "C:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\sre_parse.py", line 638, in
_parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
```

What is going on?

Comment: "I think the error isn't even in my code." - get used to the problem being in your code. It almost always is. Did you look at the line in your code that the traceback is pointing to? There's a problem in your regex syntax.

Comment: Hint: a `+` sign is special; you'll want to escape it.

Comment: @Poeder the most interesting line is the first one of the traceback. It shows you, where the error is in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your regex patterns here: https://regex101.com/r/eY4aT8/1. They are explained in detail and errors are depicted.

The problem is your regex pattern `+31 6 \d{8}` - it cannot just start with a `+` with nothing on the left of that `+`.

Comment: I'm confused, don't the " ' "s make everything inside re.compile a string? You can't add values from a string, right?

Comment: Your regex pattern is in inside `'...'` or `"..."`, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#match-objects)

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant. :p So this isn't a string at all? That'd explain quite a bit haha

Comment: @Poeder: It is a string. You're passing the string to the regex engine to be interpreted as a regular expression, and `+` has special meaning in regular expression syntax. The fact that it's a string doesn't prevent this.